# Modifiying the linux system kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, self-modifying

i want to modify the system kernell for linux, i want to change the open system call, so when i try to open one file, i want to open another one, but i cannot find where in the open.c file this can be done and which variables to work with, would appreciate some information. There are a lot of syscalls_defines in the open systemcall, but i do not understand which one of them i could work with. I have tried to add some printk() functions into some functions in the open.c, and when i sudo dmesg i get there output, but i still can't find exactly which functions that open.c calls and which function to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but if you just want to hijack the open system call without the malign intention of applying this to all processes on a machine, you don't need to tinker with the kernel. Using shared library magic with LD_PRELOAD, and redefining the libc system call wrapper would probably be enough.

You can find how to do this with read and write [here](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/low-level/kernel/2016/08/29/16-48-53-the_-ld_preload-_trick/). But the idea is the same with any system call.